# Open VLC in background

Tags: vlc-media-player

I have a program that opens VLC to play a sound, but I don't want that other people see the VLC player, since I mirror my screen on a TV. Is it possible that I can make VLC open in background or minimalized?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The command line parameter for opening VLC minimized(in system tray) is `--qt-start-minimized`. Example usage:

```
"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" --qt-start-minimized
```

Answer (score 11):

#### On windows 10, using vlc 2.2.4:

Using `vlc -I null --play-and-exit [arguments]`, vlc opens in the background without appearing in the taskbar or system tray.

However, it can be seen when 'more details' is clicked in task manager.

For example, when you want to play audio while vlc is hidden:

```
vlc -I null --play-and-exit "C:\Windows.old\Users\Public\Music\Sample Music\Kalimba.mp3"
```

Comment: Great answer! But vlc will stay running after the file is played.  To auto-exit after the file has finished playing you can add the `--play-and-exit` flag

Answer (score 0):

`-Incurse` Also works, shows only in task manager.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux, you can use the command `cvlc` instead of `vlc`. And then add `--play-and-exit`. It will run a single process that will exit after playing the file.

Example usage :
`cvlc --play-and-exit ./my-audio-file.wav`

I was not able to make `-Incurse` or `-I null` work, and `--qt-start-minimized` called a notification in Plasma6 which is undesirable for my use-case.